# Can't connect to wifi during Arch Linux install

Tags: linux, arch-linux, wifi-configuration

I'm trying to install Arch Linux from scratch following the official installation guide. Although an Ethernet connection is recommended, my computer doesn't have an Ethernet port, so I must use wifi. I successfully connected to wifi using the `wifi-menu` command, but when I try to ping any site this happens:

```sh
ping google.com
ping: google.com: Name or service not known
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: edit /etc/resolv.conf ; replace whatever address is there with 8.8.8.8

Comment: Can you ping your router?

Comment: @Madhubala it didn't work

Comment: @singalongconflict no, I get the same error message (I pinged 192.168.1.1, which I found using the command `ip route | grep default`)

Comment: Hmm, that's so strange. It seems that, while your computer is technically connected network, your computer can't make use of that connection. I found [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=133307) which seems to be related to your situation. Unfortunately, that's the best that I can help with :( . Best of luck!

Comment: One final thing you could try is using another Linux live USB (preferably something that attempts to auto configure everything like Ubuntu). If your computer can access the internet in Ubuntu, at least you know something is wrong with Arch (either configuration or drivers) rather than something being possibly wrong with your computer's networking.

Comment: @singalongconflict I did exactly this after asking on the arch forums and it worked... apparently it has to do with the new arch installation ISO relying on systemd-networkd instead of dhcpcd. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yay. Glad you were able to solve it!

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a problem with systemd-networkd not working right with wifi-menu. I solved it using the previous Arch ISO instead of the newest one (when it was still using dhcpcd instead of systemd-networkd) and it worked fine.